# characters not showing properly in git bash integrated terminal visual studio code

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code, git-bash

[here is what is happening](https://gyazo.com/b30bf90d797ef770ca596754b5a84abb)

I had no issue when i installed it first, everything was fine, but second time i opened my VSC this happend.

I tried changing to xterm-256color but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The data in screenshot showed terminal escape characters that changed
the text color back and forth.

and the thing that received output did not know how to handle those
(not a real terminal emulator) (but thought output is a tty)

You could try to set term to 'dumb'

Comment: well, how do i set terminal to 'dumb'?

Comment: Run `export TERM=dumb` before executing the other command (or if that is difficult, try putting it into your `.bashrc`)

Comment: well , that did not help at all, the only thing that did is that my clear command didn't work after i put it in .bashrc or running it in terminal before typing command..